# How to change a new line not started by a (") character to another string

Tags: regex, string, sed

I need to change a newline not started by `"` (quote) to another printable word, Like `\n` or `<br>`.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
cat file.csv | sed 's/^[^\"]/\<br\>/g'
```

An example of an input file:

```
cat file.csv

"a","bcde","fgh
ijk
   mnopq
asd"
```

The output I need:

```
cat file.csv

"a","bcde","fgh<br>ijk<br>   mnopq<br>asd"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think targeting a newline that isn't followed by a double quote is a reliable way to do what you want. For instance, it doesn't handle cases like this one:

```
"abc","def
"
```

A more reliable way consists to check if there's an odd number of double quotes in a line and to append next lines until this number becomes even, then you can proceed to the replacement:

```
sed -E '/^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*$/{:a;N;/^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$/{s/\n/<br>/g;bb};ba;};:b;' file
```

`-E` switches the regex syntax to ERE (Extended Regular Expression)
`-i` changes the file content in-place (When you are sure, add this switch)

command details:

```
/^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*$/ # check if the line has an odd number of quotes
{ # when the match succeeds:
    :a; # define a label "a"
    N;  # append the next line to the pattern space
    /^("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$/ # check if the pattern space contains an even number of quotes
    { # in this case:
       s/\n/<br>/g; # proceed to the replacement
       bb; # go to label "b"
    };
    ba; # go to label "a"
};
:b; # define the label "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional branching in `sed`:

```
sed -i -E ':a;N;s~\n([^"])~<br\>\1~;ba' file.csv

# check results    
cat file.csv

"a","bcde","fgh<br>ijk<br>   mnopq<br>asd"
```

[Read more about it](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/)

Comment: thank you. but i have an especific line with only a quote

Comment: abcd
"
"a","a"

what i do to up this quote on line 2 to end of line 1?

Comment: Don't post any data in quotes other it will lose formatting. Better you show the new input in question so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @JackMagor: You can use: `sed -E ':a;N;s~\n([^"])~<br\>\1~;ba; :a;N;s/\n"\n/"\n/g;ba' file.csv`